# Vue i18n doesn't update in store when switching language in components

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-i18n

I have a store module containing `i18n` data in state variables:

```
import i18n from '@/localization';
export default {
  state: {
    title: i18n.t('title'),
    recommendation: i18n.t('recommendation')
  ...
```

Problem: in this module, `i18n` is never updated when user changes language. It is as if the `import i18n` here was done only once and for all.

How can I make this reactive, so that this store module re-imports `i18n` every time language changes or updates it properly?

EDIT:
The `i18n` imported in my store module is the same one that is imported then used in root Vue instance, this is my `main.js` where you can see the import comes from the same file `localization.js`:

```
import i18n from '@/localization';
const vm = new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  i18n,
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

Comment: If you are importing the same `i18n` in your root Vue instance - then chaging `i18n.locale` should have the same effect both in your components and the Vuex store.

Comment: Yes it's the same, I edited the question to make that clear.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Vuex state is initialized only once - if you want the state to react on your locale change than you should commit a mutation which will update the state with the current locale - `mutations: changeLocale(state, locale) { state.title = i18n.t("title"); ... }` Or, if these texts never change - then either use a Vuex getter to make them notice the locale change, or even better - move those constant texts outside of Vuex.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice, I ended up moving them out of the state indeed!